# Same height inline blocks alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to align a few even number of inline blocks as below:

```
        _____   _____   _____   _____         
       |     | |     | |     | |     |     
       |  1  | |  2  | |  3  | |  4  |
       |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____|
                _____   _____    
               |     | |     |
               |  5  | |  6  |
               |_____| |_____|
```

The problem is: when there is extra content in any of the blocks, the boxes are misaligned.
Please check the below link:

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5JSAG/45/)

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Is the problem that the blocks are out of alignment or that the block with the 12 content isn't centered?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top`  to your css code.

```
.entry 
{ 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    padding-top:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top; /* added */
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5JSAG/51/)

Answer (score 1):

use `vertical-align: top;` for inline-block elements - http://jsfiddle.net/5JSAG/49/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.entry 
{ 
display:inline-block;
margin-top:10px;
width:100px;
height:60px;
padding-top:40px;
border:1px solid red;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5JSAG/63/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using absolute positioning to break your .entry divs free from the document flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/TQW3D/1/

```
.entry 
{ 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}

.entry span
{
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```